# Seating Plan Using Gdrive and Gsheets

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to build a seating chart for teachers that will accept the student name (from a drop down box) match it with their student number and then insert the image file (stored in a GDrive folder under "studentnumber".jpg) into a cell above the name.

The answers I have been able to find are ones where the sharing of all the images are set to public and findable...obviously, I cannot do this with student pictures due to privacy concerns. Any ideas or workarounds?

I have already used the script from "http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86081/insert-image-from-google-drive-into-google-sheets" so I have the "google" filenames/links but it will not display the image. Once I have the images displaying, I can program the rest.

Comment: At October 30, 2018, new Class and some methods for using images on Spreadsheet were added and updated, respectively. From this, I think that in your situation, new class of OverGridImage and the updated method of ``insertImage()`` might be able to be used. You can see the documents of them at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource-column-row) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image).

Comment: @Tanaike I've been playing around trying to insertImages() and I only seem to be able to insert pngs into spreadsheet cells.  Is that a limitation or is it just me.

Comment: @Cooper In my environment, image files with the mimeTypes of image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp and image/gif can be inserted to Spreadsheet. But I have not confirmed whether all various files can be used for this situation. So for example, how about changing mimeType using ``getAs()``? I apologize for my abstract answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it to work and you have helped make a school very happy.

Comment: @Mr. M. Perzan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.